# Apply code to a gameObject with EventTrigger

Tags: android, touch

I have a button for which i'd like to signify "attacking". I'm programming for android.

Basically i'd like to run this script, upon the touch of the attack button. Instead of using the F key to stop the code from rapidly repeating, i'm trying to figure out how to run an if statement for "if button is touched & !isAttacking" then go into the method.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F) && !isAttacking)
     {
         isAttacking = true;
         attackTimer = attackCD;
         Debug.Log("F Pressed");

         attackTrigger.enabled = true;
     }

     if (isAttacking)
     {
         if (attackTimer > 0)
         {
             attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
         }
         else
         {
             isAttacking = false;
             attackTrigger.enabled = false;
         }
     }
```

I'm using Unity 5!

Comment: Set an onClickListener/onTouchListener to the button and in that method check !isAttacking.

Comment: I'm using Unity 5, but the problem is that in the if statement it's waiting for a trigger. at the moment it's the GetKeyDown. If i were to remove the GetKeyDown, the code would loop due to it saying " If the character is not attacking, set isAttacking to true. " I need to replace the GetKeyDown with another Input, which is touch.

Comment: I don't understand :s why don't you just remove the first if from the gameloop and add it to a listener? Then you can remove the getKeyDown.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you'd do that?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on buttons for unity: [UI Button](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button?playlist=17111). But I'll look for a code sample

Comment: In pseudo code: button = getcomponent;   button.onClick.AddListener(your_method);